# How to Save Email To Hard Disk/or any external System like Azure Storage or One Drive using Office JS

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am New to Office Add in Development. I have to create outlook Add in that will be used to save Email to Azure Storage and One Drive
I have developed add in Using React JS and Office JS.

Thanks and Advance

I have tried Office JS `SaveAsync()` method but now luck

Comment: You are working on Message Read mode or compose mode

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript API for Office (`OfficeJS`) doesn't provide any method or property for saving items to any cloud storage. The `SaveAsync` method saves the item to the Outlook store (Exchange).

To save or upload an Outlook item to any cloud storage you can upload the item  by reading its property values and submitting these values on the per-property basis. Or just consider using a service which can accept the item ID and can retrieve the item via Graph API at any convenient place where you need to save the item. See [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for more information.